# common table expression with insert select

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the correct syntax to use a common table expression in an insert select ? I am using SQL Server 2016. Something like (code not valid):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Id, ROUND(SUM(PdsS),3) AS sum_PdsS
    FROM #t1
    GROUP BY Id
)
INSERT INTO #t2
SELECT ...
FROM #t3 AS a
JOIN cte AS b ON a.Id=cte.Id
```

Comment: that code is valid (in general). What error are you getting?

Comment: It was the issue

Comment: @Han `;` is a statement **terminator** not a "beginningator". it goes on the end of the statements, not the start of a Common Table Expression. The OP should be terminator their prior statement(s) properly (and the statement using the CTE).

Comment: Teaching with like `;WITH CTE` tends to introduce poor practices. The amount of times I've seen `:WITH CTE1 AS (...),; CTE2 AS` and people ask why "it doesn't work" isn't low. A `WITH` statement doesn't "start" with a semicolon; and neither does a `MERGE` *(they do, however, both **end** with a semicolon)*.

Comment: To elaborate on @Larnu comments, the reason you tend to see it as `;with` is because SSMS doesn't *generally* force you to terminate statements with a `;`. However, *When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon.* [Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). So, this semicolon isn't at the beginning of the cte, it's simply at the end of the previous statement... and the end is anywhere before the next statement which is your `CTE` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in the question is actually correct. a semi colon was missing to finish the previous expression.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be

```
    1. INSERT INTO
    2. WITH CTE AS (...)
    3. SELECT
```

?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. My syntax was actually right. All that was missing is a ; (semi colon) at the end of the previous instruction.